# What am I doing wrong with making the corner radius exposed in Interface Builder?

Tags: uiimageview, interface-builder, swift, ios8, xcode6

This is driving me nutty. I added a new framework and added a `UIImageView` subclass to be part of it. I then created a `UITableViewCell`, made it an instance of my custom `UIImageView` and set its exposed corner radius to 5.

In my subclass I just have:

```
@IBDesignable class MediaPostCellImageView: UIImageView {
    @IBInspectable var cornerRadius: CGFloat = 3.0 {
        didSet {
            self.layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
        }
    }
}
```

Here's an example project showing it: http://cl.ly/3Z053m1O3C0i

Why is this not showing it in Interface Builder?

Comment: Set clipsToBounds property of your image view

Comment: @Eugene That did nothing.

Comment: When you say it is not showing, do you mean nothing is showing at all?

Comment: I downloaded your sample project but it does not contain the MediaPostCellImageView class

Comment: I'm seeing the same problem, it appears that layer.cornerRadius is not honored at design time, even though it works correctly at runtime. I suspect this is a side-effect of the magic xcode is doing to get a UIView translated into something that runs in OS/X. Has anyone come up with a workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `layer.masksToBounds` property to `true`.

Also, if you still can't see the rounded corner, try to change the background colour, just in case it actually has rounded corners but you can't see it because the colours are the same with the superview.

Answer (score 0):

```
    @IBInspectable var cornerRadius: CGFloat {
    get { layer.cornerRadius }
    set {
        layer.cornerRadius = newValue
        if newValue > 0 {
            layer.masksToBounds = true
        }
    }
}
```

You can use something like this in the extension. Once the new value is set for the corner radius and it's greater than 0, layer.maskToBounds is set to true.